# switching between row wise and normal calculation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I guess I have just a small problem but I don't know how to solve it. I want to calculate the `max` value per row and have a column with the rank depending on a category.

```
df <- data.frame(cat=rep(letters[1:5], each=5),
                 a=runif(25),
                 b=runif(25),
                 c=runif(25))

df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(MAX=max(a,b,c),
         RANK=rank(MAX))
```

The rank is always 1, I guess because of the `rowwise` function call but not sure.

Is there also a way to automatically use all columns except the `cat` column?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pmax` instead:

```
df %>%
   group_by(cat) %>%
   mutate(MAX = pmax(a,b,c), RANK = rank(MAX))

#Source: local data frame [25 x 6]
#Groups: cat [5]
#
#      cat         a         b         c       MAX  RANK
#   (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl) (dbl)
#1       a 0.8514743 0.4051721 0.5547097 0.8514743     3
#2       a 0.2599851 0.3559089 0.2878979 0.3559089     1
#3       a 0.1269608 0.6784622 0.1088647 0.6784622     2
#4       a 0.6764552 0.9013046 0.8811285 0.9013046     4
#5       a 0.9284667 0.3482491 0.9241917 0.9284667     5
#6       b 0.7799539 0.8811926 0.6788580 0.8811926     3
#7       b 0.8974519 0.8499074 0.1847301 0.8974519     4
#8       b 0.6819014 0.9334878 0.6150482 0.9334878     5
#9       b 0.2539325 0.1707934 0.2902184 0.2902184     1
#10      b 0.7913689 0.5555206 0.3349121 0.7913689     2
#..    ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   ...
```

`pmax` and `pmin` return the **p**arallel maxima and minima of the input values. That means, you don't need to group by row (using `rowwise`).

Small example:

```
pmax(1:5, 5:1)
#[1] 5 4 3 4 5
```

If you need more flexibility, you can do it in two steps:

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(MAX = max(a,b,c)) %>% 
    group_by(cat) %>% 
    mutate(RANK = rank(MAX))
```

But for the described example, `pmax` is clearly a better approach.

Another option is to use `rowMeans`:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(MAX = rowMeans(.[c('a','b','c')])) %>% 
    group_by(cat) %>% 
    mutate(RANK = rank(MAX))
```

If you don't want to specify the column names manually, you could use `do.call` and exclude the first column:

```
df %>% mutate(MAX = do.call(pmax, .[-1]))
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to it? I basically tried the same with `mean` and a ranking of the averages... I guess there is no `pmean`?!

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. Is there a way to get the column names automatically? I tried `pmax(names(df)[-1])` but this does not seems to work.

Comment: see `help("which.max")`

Comment: @drmariod, see the last bit of my answer

Comment: Thanks, that helped! In the end it was a bit different on my side, since I use `data.table` instead of `data.frame` but I got it to work. Thanks.